# jQuery redirect to another view from a view with parameters

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I wish to redirect to view 2 when I click a button at view 1.

I manage to redirect it to view 2 but it will automatically execute a method at controller which hit error due to passing null values.

Below are my codes:

```
 url = '/ConsignmentSale/Detail/';

 $(this).dialog("close");
 window.location = url;
 $.ajax({
     url: '/ConsignmentSale/Detail',
     data: ({ id: $("#LID").val(), c1: result }),
```

It have values when call the method directly with ajax. But null values when redirect from view 1 to view 2.

Any advice to solve it?

Comment: I need to pass in values to generate a set of data to bind.

Comment: if value can be null, in your controller they should be nullable

Comment: I cannot do that. I need to pass in some values to generate a set of data to bind at view 2.

Comment: How do you redirect from View1 to View2?

Comment: window.location = url;

Comment: Ajax method will never run because window.location = url already redirect to location

Comment: Please share more detail ...

Comment: I have found the solution for it. 
url = '/ConsignmentSale/Detail/?id=' + id + '&c1=' + result;

It will redirect to view 2 and pass parameters.